# Mocha test React-Native throws ReferenceError: __DEV__ is not defined

Tags: react-native, mocha.js, atom-editor

I'm using Atom and the Mocha Test Runner. I'm getting ReferenceError: **DEV** is not defined when I try to run a test against React-Native (0.33)

The **DEV** variable is referenced in various react-native core modules.

My mocha test runner options are:
--compilers js:babel-register --opts test/mocha.opts --harmony-proxies test/setup.js

My setup.js looks like this

```
import chai from "chai";
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import register from 'babel-core/register';
import chaiEnzyme from 'chai-enzyme';

const modulesToCompile = [
  'react-native',
  'react-native-tabs',
  'react-native-vector-icons',
  'react-native-mock',
  'react-native-parallax-scroll-view'
].map((moduleName) => new RegExp(`/node_modules/${moduleName}`));

function getBabelRC() {
  var rcpath = path.join(__dirname, '..', '.babelrc');
  var source = fs.readFileSync(rcpath).toString();
  return JSON.parse(source);
}

var config = getBabelRC();

config.ignore = function(filename) {
  if (!(/\/node_modules\//).test(filename)) {
    return false;
  } else {
    const matches = modulesToCompile.filter((regex) => regex.test(filename));
    const shouldIgnore = matches.length === 0;
    return shouldIgnore;
  }
}

register(config);

global.__DEV__ = true;
global.expect = chai.expect;
chai.use(chaiEnzyme());

require('react-native-mock/mock');
const React = require('react-native')
React.NavigationExperimental = {
  AnimatedView: React.View
};
```

Any idea how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I had deleted a parameter in the Mocha setup, it should be

```
--compilers js:babel-register --opts test/mocha.opts --harmony-proxies --require test/setup.js
```